# how to say something have been hidden in view of people/ scientists

Tags: sentence-construction, vocabulary, phrase-request

When it comes to saying the fact or something have been **hidden from *views*** or ***eyes***, what do you say? not from mind. I need some phrase or words used scientifically.

For instance:

> The importance of some microorganisms in water has been neglected.

Comment: Are you asking for an idiom related to being hidden or obscure, which means "has been neglected"? If so, we say "The importance of water has not been recognized."

Comment: Your example with water conveys a mental sense, not literal - yet you say "not from the mind". You cannot literally overlook the *importance* of water, it's a mental lapse, not physiological. If you come up with clearer example sentences it would be easier to offer a proper expression.

Comment: Probably, *has gone unnoticed*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few different possibilities here. If the meaning is that something is very easy to notice, but the scientists were focused on something else, you could say something like:

> Their first attempts at prairie restorations failed because they ignored the importance of the humble ant in the ecosystem.
>
> Their first attempts at prairie restorations failed because they did not realize/recognize the importance of the humble ant in the ecosystem.

There is a phrase that I think might be useful to you for this type of situation. It is "hiding in plain sight". That is something that you should be able to see, but don't notice because you aren't looking for it. For example:

> A new species of spider was just discovered in Central Park in New York City. Usually new species are found in unexplored places, but in this case the spider was hiding in plain sight.